# ember-cli & common route and controller behavior options: Subclass, Mixin or initializer (service)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have properties and methods I want exposed to most/all instances of a class (i.e. all but a handful of routes, controllers, whatever). There seems to be multiple ways to accomplish this and I'm looking for guidance for best practices here.

More specifically, I've created a property on my application controller to hold a user session object. I want all other controllers to expose this data as if I had typed:

```
needs: ['application'],
userSession: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.userSession')
```

directly into the controller.

Further, I want to override all routes (other than the login route and maybe a couple more) implementations of beforeModel to check for the presence of userSession and redirect to the login route if absent.

This is being implemented in ember-cli FYI. So, that being the case, what's the "right" approach here? Do I try to inject these changes via initializers/services? Do I create mix-ins to do this stuff (I'm not a fan of having to remember to do that every time someone working on this does ember g controller that they then have to remember to add the mixin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds very much like the use of an `initializer` *and* a `service` is the best approach (them being split up makes for cleaner code). The `initializer` is just the code to load the `service`, the service does the hard work. The `initializer` should look something like:

```
import AuthService from '../services/auth';

export default {
  name: 'auth-service',
  initialize: function( container, app ) {
    app.register( 'service:auth', AuthService, { singleton: true } );
    app.inject( 'controller', 'auth', 'service:auth' );
    app.inject( 'route', 'auth', 'service:auth' );
  }
};
```

This then injects `auth` into every controller and route, and you should move the `userSession` from your application to the service.

My auth service is too big (and in my case: too specific, as it uses Firebase) to be quoting it here. I gave the gist of it in an answer yesterday: [Short delay when trying to run redirect with ember route with firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852290/short-delay-when-trying-to-run-redirect-with-ember-route-with-firebase-authentic/25854719#25854719)

And as you mentioned it: people don't strictly need to remember to include mixins as you can override the blueprint that is used when someone does `ember generate`: http://www.ember-cli.com/#generators-and-blueprints

Comment: I wondered if monkeying with the blueprints was the answer if I went the mixin route. Talking it over here in the office we were leaning towards your proposed solution but weren't sure if that was the idiomatic "ember" way or not. I'll give it a go and mark as answered if all goes well.

Comment: You did say (and I'm finding myself in the same spot) that you'll need the authorisation service in the majority of your routes / controllers. That in itself is a hint you should be injecting it, rather than `needs`-ing a controller. If you needed it only in a few controllers then injecting it in those specifically might still be the cleanest solution with the least boilerplate, though not necessarily obvious that it is injected from the pov of the controller itself.

Comment: As I'm implementing this it occurs to me that only solves half of my problem. This will move the "session" information to an injected property but does not deal with the *mostly* default behavior of routes to override the beforeModel hook to redirect to login in certain cases. Or, are you suggesting mixins for that part? It's unclear to me how to inject that behavior...

Comment: That's more worthy of a question in itself. You have to be prepared that a user can always use a browser's dev tools to give themselves access to your protected pages. In other words, restrict read access to the data based on the actual authentication status on the Firebase end. To handle it on a router level, this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234810/protecting-a-route-using-firebase-simple-login

Comment: In my case, it doesn't really matter security-wise if they monkey-around to get access to a route they aren't supposed to because without the auth service having session data in it, no services to the back-end will work (i.e. the data is protected). It's really just a user-experience thing. What I ended up doing was creating a "AuthenicatedRoute" that implements a beforeModel hook like I wanted. Then I created a new blueprint such that when I do ember g route, it will automatically extend my AuthenicatedRoute by default. Seems to work OK.